# Getting a error while using fetch on reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api

I use fect() from react to make a post request to an api like so:

[image]

Which returns the following errors:

Console:

[image]

Network:

[image]

Although when I use Postman everything works fantastic.

[image]
Api doc:
[image]
Any idea on what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `name` is expected to be an object but is being sent as a string, I know this seems to work fine in Postman but can you shed some light on it?

Comment: I tried doesn't seem to work, you can check what I did in the edited first print  @GhassenLouhaichi.

Comment: I don't know how it's working with Postman but it seems that the API is indeed expecting an object, have you tried defining the name attribute as `name: { name: 'foobar' }` and sending it using fetch like that?

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work but thanks!